# Sending Image Bytes

Tags: c#, image, sockets

I made this code to take a screenshot - convert it to bytes -send it to my client 
but when the client receives it it becomes the half.

Here is the code, which converts the screenshot to bytes and then send it to my client Code:

```
 public void SendImage()
        {
            int ScreenWidth = Screen.GetBounds(new Point(0, 0)).Width;
            int ScreenHeight = Screen.GetBounds(new Point(0, 0)).Height;
            Bitmap bmpScreenShot = new Bitmap(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight);



            Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage((Image)bmpScreenShot);
            gfx.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight));
            bmpScreenShot.Save(Application.StartupPath + "/ScreenShot.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] image = new byte[10000*10000*10];
            bmpScreenShot = ResizeBitmap(bmpScreenShot, 300, 300);
            image = ImageToByte(bmpScreenShot);



            sck.Send(image, 0, image.Length, 0);

        }
```

And Here IS The Receive Code

```
public void ReceiveImage()
    {

        if (sck.Connected)
        {

            {
                NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(sck);
                byte[] data = new byte[10000 * 10000 * 3];
                string receive = string.Empty;
                Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                pictureBox1.Image = byteArrayToImage(data);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: First thing I noticed, sender allocates `10000*10000*10` and receiver allocates `10000 * 10000 * 3` bytes. Why the disparity?

Answer (score 2):

You are sending 1000 * 1000 * 10 bytes and you are receiving 1000 * 1000 * 3 bytes.

Also make sure you read from the stream for as long as there is more.

A more secure way would be to send the size of the array first.

So after turning the image into a JPG, get the amount of bytes, send this amount in 4 bytes, read these 4 bytes, prepare a buffer of that size and read the stream.

**More hints**

```
image = ImageToByte(bmpScreenShot);

// get the encoded image size in bytes
int numberOfBytes = image.Length;

// put the size into an array
byte[] numberOfBytesArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(numberOfBytes);

// send the image size to the server
sck.Send(numberOfBytesArray, 0, numberOfBytesArray.Length, 0);

// send the image to the server
sck.Send(image, 0, numberOfBytes, 0);
```

Server

```
NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(sck);
byte[] data = new byte[4];

// read the size
stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(data);

// prepare buffer
data = new byte[size];

// load image
stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Comment: its my first server and client can you give me some code so i can understand what you are saying???

Comment: and i tried to make it 1000*1000*3 and receive it as 1000*1000*3 and it didn't work

Comment: how can i send the buffersize do i need , and how do i prepare it , can you help me??

Comment: umm. after i read the image in the stream how can i read it in a picturebox??

Comment: You could save it first (you did sent a jpg after all) or you could load the stream into a MemoryStream and use `Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(memoryStream);`

Comment: when i try to save them it gives me this error(parrament not valid)

Comment: Please, when mentioning an error without code we can only guess.

Comment: public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
}

Answer (score 2):

For a start, this code is broken:

```
byte[] data = new byte[10000 * 10000 * 3];
Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
```

You're *assuming* you'll receive the data in a single call to `Read`. You mustn't assume that - it's a *streaming* protocol. You should loop round until `Read` returns 0... or prefix the data with the length of the "message" you're sending.

Additionally, it's not clear what `ResizeBitmap` or `ImageToByte` do, but it's odd to have to preallocate an array when you really don't know how many bytes you need...

Comment: umm..didnt understand anything

Comment: @TarekAdel: Then I suggest you read a tutorial on stream-based IO. There's no guarantee that a call to `Stream.Read` will return as much data as you've asked for. It's not clear what protocol you're using - are you expecting to have multiple images on the same connection, or are you going to send an image and then close the connection? If it's the latter, you should just keep reading (possibly putting the results into a `MemoryStream` to make things easier) until the stream runs out of data. If you need to put multiple images (or images and other data) on the same connection (cont)

Comment: ... you'll need to add some sort of delimiter or length prefix for the data.

Comment: can you add me on Facebook , i need to talk to you a little so i can understand ,this is my Facebook email tarek55544@live.com

Comment: @TarekAdel: No, I'm not going to go to Facebook for this. Read the answer and comments *carefully*, read around the topic in IO tutorials and I'm sure you'll figure it out.

Comment: i read tutorials like for 4 days and this passed on me but i also need help in it, im still a 13 years old and this is my first server / client app